# steps for indexing nested documents in Solr

Tags: json, indexing, solr

I've read a lot about indexing nested documents in Solr, but none of the answers gave a clear way to do it : 
Some have talked about flattening the documents, but how could that be done? 
what I have is a document of this strucure :

```
- level1 :{
    level2 : {
       level3 :{ 
             field1: value1,
             field2: value2,
               }
             }
          }
```

In my schema.xml, my understanding of flattening the document is to pretend the nested documents don't exist, so I simply added to schema.xml : 
field1 , field2 , however when the documents are indexed, these fields are not shown in the result of a query. 
Can anyone please explain how I can index this type of documents in Solr ?

Thank you

Comment: A "flattened" document could still keep level1, level2 as names, such as `"level1_level2_level3_field1": value1, "level1_level2_level3_field2": value2` . Anyway - they should be available when querying if you're indexing them (even as just field1/field2), as long as you include them in `fl` (or use `fl=*`). Are you sure you're submitting the documents correctly in that case? The reason why flattening is recommended is because it makes everything easier when querying Solr, as it's inherently a "flat" document store.

Comment: it might be more flexible to hold the document structure in a multivalued string field, if this is important.

Comment: @MatsLindh in localhost:8983/solr/mycore/schema-browser I find the fields that I indexed in schema.xml, however what do you mean by submit the documents correctly? beause what I have is documents in MongoDB and what I do is : localhost:8983/solr/mycore/dataimport?command=full-import , and then if I do a query, the specific fields don't appear

Comment: Are you using the schemaless mode or with a specific schema?

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm using a specific schema that I define in schema.xml (with <field></field>)